# Phonegap Vs Intel xdk Vs Ionic

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cross-platform, phonegap-build, intel-xdk

today i want to know about : what is the best hybrid mobile platform , Phone-gap vs Ionic Vs Intel xdk ?
you can talk about the advantages and disadvantages , about the performance and the platforms supported from each framework ?

Comment: Your question is asking for opinions, which is not the purpose of Stackoverflow. Your question has been flag for deletion.